# FileSystemException The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process Can't correctly clear result files after test

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

I have a method that should accept data from one CSV file, change the data and transfer it to a new CSV file. But I get the following error. Why?

```java
public void getStatistic(String fromFileName, String toFileName) throws IOException {
    List <String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFileName));
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(toFileName,true));
    while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
        String[] rows = bufferedReader.readLine().split(",");
        list.add(rows);
    }
    for (String[] str : list) {
        set.add(str[0]);
        for (String sk : str) {
            System.out.println("1 " + sk);
        }
    }
    for (String sets : set) {
        int num = 0;
        for (String[] str : list) {
            if (str[0].equals(sets)) {
                num += Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            }
            bufferedWriter.write(sets + "," + num + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `close()` your `bufferedReader` and `bufferedWriter` at the end of your method.

Comment: Also, look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html to prevent such errors.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are objects that represent something more than just some memory. For example, an open network connection, or an open file handle, or a live connection to a database.

Those underlying things are **severely limited**. You can make a million objects. No problem. That DB isn't going to let you have more than about 50 open connections, though.

So, whilst objects you can just forget about (the garbage collector will eventually get around to cleaning that up), **resources are not like that**. You have to explicitly close them the moment you are done with them.

Your problem is: You aren't doing that.

The only proper way to deal with resources is to ensure you close them *regardless* of how your code flows. So, even if an exception occurs, even if you `return` in the middle of a method, the resource must be closed.

In addition, as the name suggests, a `BufferedWriter` **buffers**. Meaning, if you don't tell that writer to 'flush' its buffer, you'll have half a CSV file on disk, with the other half still in that buffer.

We solve both problems in one swoop by writing this properly.

```
try (
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFileName));
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(toFileName, true))) {

  .. use the stuff here ..
}
```

This construct (The `try` part) ensures that no matter how code exits the braces (be it by just getting to the end, or you `return` or `break` or `continue` out of it, or an exception happens), `.close()` will be called on those 2 items. That will cause the buffer to 'flush' its data and then close the thing it wrapped (your `FileWriter`).

NB: Calling `ready()` is not how you do this; ready is not what you use to check if there's still data to read. Instead, call `.readLine()`, and if that returns `null` - *that* is the signal you got to the end of the file. You can use a `while(true)` and a `break` to do this, or for example `for (String readLine = in.readLine(); readLine != null; readLine = in.readLine()) {`